# UI integration tests for vscode extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to implement end to end testing for my vscode extension. For command we implemented in package.json & run tasks intergated that takes input parameter as pickString, promptString, etc. How to write intergation test case to pick UI elements in vscode?

Do we have any sample UI integration tests for vscode extensions?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem with an extension I am working on. 
You should check the [vscode docs on testing](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/testing-extension) as they have a way to run tests.

Another project I have been working on is a way to run tests using [Cypress.io](https://www.cypress.io/). That enabled me to write more functional test cases. I am still exploring best practices for that, but if you are interested here is my blog post: https://juanmanuelalloron.com/2020/05/05/testing-vscode-extensions-with-cypress-and-code-server/

and some boilerplate code that I have on github: https://github.com/juanallo/vscode-e2e-cypress-boilerplate

Comment: Hi
I have gone through your blog post. Is there a way to automate the clicking action. it looked to me that a person need to click a button. it is it possible to automate that clicking action?